# Frustrated trying to read a path from an argument in C#

Tags: c#

I'm passing /file:c:\myfile.doc and I'm getting back "/file:c:\myfile.doc" instead of "C:\myfile.doc", could someone please advise where I am going wrong?

```
            if (entry.ToUpper().IndexOf("FILE") != -1)
            {
                //override default log location
                MyFileLocation = entry.Split(new char[] {'='})[1];
            }
```

Answer (score 6):

You are splitting on "=" instead of ":"

Try

```
    if (entry.ToUpper().IndexOf("FILE:") == 0)
    {
         //override default log location
         MyFileLocation location = entry.Split(new char[] {':'},2)[1];
    }
```

Comment: This also fixes a problem where file exists somewhere in the middle of file name and matches erroneously and accounts for multiple colons in the string by splitting into at most 2 substrings.

Comment: If your input string doesn't have a ":" this code will throw an OutOfRangeException. You should check that.

Comment: It's guaranteed to have a colon since it must match the string "FILE:"

Comment: Note that there may be better ways to do this -- I just wanted to show how to fix the given code.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to just take a substring. Since you are reading this from the command line, the "/file:" portion will always be consistent.

```
entry.Substring(6);
```

This will return everything after the "/file:".

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer as I think it's been answered well enough already, but as you stated that you're a beginner I thought that I would point out that:

```
entry.split(new char[]{':'});
```

can be:

```
entry.split(':');
```

This uses:

```
split(params char[] separator);
```

This can be deceiving for new C# programmers as the params keyword means that you can actually pass in 1 to many chars, as in:

```
entry.split(':','.',' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also just lop off the 'file:' part.  It is clearly defined and will be constant so it isn't THAT bad.  Not great, but not horrible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good example of a [command line argument parser](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/yaclap.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted would require the argument `/file=c:\myfile.doc`.

Either use that as the parameter or split on the colon (**:**) instead of equals (**=**).